# .tmp Files continually created on a network drive

Tags: excel, networking, server

I work IT Help Desk and am having an issue that I nor others I work with can figure out. I have a user who is reporting in a certain network folder, one specific Excel file is creating tons of .tmp files when opened. I verified on the Excel file that no macros are running when the file is opened. Is there a way to stop these .tmp from being continually created? If you need additional info, just let me know.

Thank you!!

Comment: Might Be a dumb question, but have to tried unplugging it and plugging it back in? lol. In other words creating a new excel fine, copying all the sheets to it, and saving it in place of the old file?

Comment: @CameronCritchlow Haha. Ah yes, that is usually my number one go to. Recreating the file is probably what I'm going to have to have them do.